# Storing user input data in HTML5

Tags: javascript, database, django, html, twitter-bootstrap

A (possible) client has a multipart questionnaire that they want coded in HTML5 (for responsiveness).  I was thinking Bootstrap 3, combined with HTML and a bit o' javascript.  However, I don't know what their options are regarding tracking the answers.

I'm new to HTML5, coming from the Flash world.  What are my options? It seems a job for a backend DB, and I know enough Django to get into trouble, so perhaps that would be the best bet?  I have done basic Django sites, but when something goes wrong, oh, it's a bit of a pain!  (I haven't found Django as user friendly as I might like)

Is there anything new and funky in HTML5 (I'm not sure how they'd get the data out of local storage)?  I'm good at HTML, but don't know all the tricky tricks in HTML5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to work with a CMS. It would greatly reduce your development time and it would help you avoid common pit-falls.

I would recommend using [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) with some sort of [plugin](http://www.gravityforms.com/features/form-builder/) as in my experience it has been the easiest to work with for small projects.

HTML5 has some new elements and a simplified syntax. Some elements have had their definitions changed (what the tags intended usage is).

Update:

Four years later, WordPress now has a REST API. A good way to store user input could be to check if they are logged in and then post information via AJAX to the API.

Answer (score 2):

Use ViewModel with Knockout.js for responsiveness. Its pretty fast.
You can see this sample Knockout.js project [here](https://github.com/karlinskid/KO).

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at the Django HTML5 Boilerplate (DH5BP) project[1](https://github.com/mattsnider/django-html5-boilerplate) on GitHub?

From the Readme.md

> The Django HTML5 Boilerplate...incorporat[es] the HTML5 Boilerplate (H5BP) project into an easy to consume Django-friendly Python package.
>
> Find out...about HTML5 Boilerplate at https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate
>
> This project differentiates itself from other H5BP to Django ports, by
>   including Fabric scripts that automatically convert new versions of
>   H5BP into a Django-friendly Python module. Ideally, this will make
>   keeping up-to-date with the latest version of H5BP trivial.